# Apply where condition only to secondary table using leftjoin with knex.js

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, where-clause, knex.js

I am using knex.js library to select all rows from a table and get a count() from a secondary table. The following code works fine:

```
    knex.schema.raw("SET sql_mode=''").then(() => {
    knex.select('empresas.id','empresas.rut','empresas.empresa','empresas.razon_social','procesos2.id','procesos2.id_empresas','procesos2.estado')
    .from('empresas')
    .leftJoin('procesos2', 'empresas.id', 'procesos2.id_empresas')
    .count('procesos2.id as total')
    .groupBy('empresas.id')
```

This query shows all rows from the table empresas and if there are rows from the table procesos2 it gets the count.

No i want to add a condition to the count, `.where('procesos2.estado', '=', 0)`

If i add this where clause i get a correct count but only shows one row and not all rows from empresas.

How to add the condition to get a count for all rows from table empresas.

Comment: I don't know `knex.js`, but in regular SQL you would put `AND procesos2.estado = 0` into the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: So you need to translate that to `knex.js` syntax.

Comment: @Barmar thanks this helped, i found a solution with your hint!

Comment: You should post your solution as an Answer, to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in knex.js to add conditions to the join statement using on() and adding condotions with andOn().

This is working

```
knex.schema.raw("SET sql_mode=''").then(() => {
    knex.select('empresas.id AS ide','empresas.rut','empresas.empresa','empresas.razon_social','procesos2.id','procesos2.id_empresas','procesos2.estado')
    .from('empresas')
    .leftJoin('procesos2', function() {
        this.on('procesos2.id_empresas ', '=', 'empresas.id')
            .andOn('procesos2.estado', '=', 0)
    })
    .count('procesos2.id as total')
    .groupBy('empresas.id')
```

Comment: hi can you help check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758885/joining-tables-to-query-database-data-knex